# How is "a" used in my program?

Tags: c++

new to learning c++ and I was wanting to understand the program ive practiced. I have a section of code I want to understand but im kind of lost.

```
   #include "stdafx.h";
   #include <iostream>;

   // getValueFromUser will read a value in from the user, and return it to the caller
   int getValueFromUser()
   {
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    return a;
   }

   int main()
   {
     int x = getValueFromUser(); // first call to getValueFromUser
     int y = getValueFromUser(); // second vall to getValueFromUser

     std::cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << x + y << std::endl;

     return 0;
   }
```

Im just wanting to know how " int a " comes into play here. If someone could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: It gets input from the user. It's a local variable that stores the input then returns it.

Comment: I fail to understand what about `a` is confusing you.

Comment: std::cin is used to get input from the standard input stream, i.e. from the console, and stores the input in the integer variable a. This value is returned as result of the function and printed in the console by std::cout.

Comment: I have a hard time grasping any sort of programing haha. I was just having trouble understanding what variable "a" was even doing in my program, and i rather just completely understand every little bit of it.

Comment: @FrankS101 thanks that's really what i was looking for, programing comes pretty hard to me and understanding it even some small code gets confusing at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare an uninitialized variable of type `int` with identifier `a`:

```
int a;
```

The user provides a value to `a`.

```
std::cin >> a;
```

A copy is returned from the function:

```
return a;
```

Calls to the `getValueFromUser()` will create a temporary `a`,
assign it to user input, and return it each time.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you have to declare variable (providing the type and name) before it's first use.
`std::cin` has to put it's output somewhere and that's why you need this additional variable.